# Is it possible to pass 2 functions to .animates complete argument?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

```
function FadeOutIn(qel, qtext, ael, atext) {
   $(qel, ael).animate({
        opacity: 0.0
    }, 1000, function() {        
        PopQuestion(qel, qtext), PopAnswers(ael, atext);
        $(qel, ael).animate({
            opacity: 1.0
        }, 1000, function() {            
        });
    });    
}
```

If I remove the PopAnswers function and its associated args it works great on PopQuestion.  I am looking to run the animation on the 2 Pop functions simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't separate function calls with a comma, use `;` instead

```
function FadeOutIn(qel, qtext, ael, atext) {
   $(qel, ael).animate({
        opacity: 0.0
    }, 1000, function() {        
        PopQuestion(qel, qtext);
        PopAnswers(ael, atext);
        $(qel, ael).animate({
            opacity: 1.0
        }, 1000, function() {            
        });
    });    
}
```

Browser console / dev tools (F12) should show you that you had a syntax error at that point